# Getting Login Services from Meteor Accounts

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to implement my own login buttons on meteor via:

```
<template name="login">
    <div id="login-buttons">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        Hello, {{currentUser.profile.name}}
        <button id='logout-button' class='small'>Sign Out</button>
    {{else}}
        <div class="service-login-buttons">
            {{#each services}}
                {{> _loginButtonsLoggedOutSingleLoginButton}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>
```

main.js:

```
Template.login.helpers({
    services: function() {
        return getLoginServices();
    }
})
```

Problem is, getLoginServices() doesn't seem to work, I also tried  `Accounts._loginButtons.getLoginServices()` , doesn't exist either.

Any ideas (accounts-ui version 1.15 if it helps) ?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on the same issue and was able to get the login buttons working.

I performed this with the packages accounts-password 1.1.1 and ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 1.2.71 installed.

My HTML looks similar to yours, but note that difference in the template that I'm calling.  I browsed through the Accounts._loginButtons object and looked through the meteor github to find a template I wanted to use [Meteor Github re: login buttons](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/832e6fe44f3635cae060415d6150c0105f2bf0f6/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons_dropdown.html)

```
<template name = "intro">
   <div class = "container-fluid black">
     <div class="service-login-buttons">
          {{#each service}}
            {{> _loginButtonsLoggedOutAllServices}}
          {{/each}}
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

For my meteor version I found that Accounts._loginButtons.getLoginServices() worked for returning the login services available.  If this doesn't work can you take a look at the Accounts._loginButtons object to see what is available?

```
Template.intro.helpers({

      service:function(){
          return Accounts._loginButtons.getLoginServices();
      }
})
```